# System Requirement for Spark In Production

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

May someone please help me with the system requirement for Spark to run on Production Environment.

I am trying to set up Environment for Batch Processing of data coming from Kafka Producer.

The size of data daily process is in TB.
The Data is coming from HDFS,and Persistant layer is also HDFS.

The information i got are:-

```
4-8 disks per node, configured without RAID (just as separate mount points).
Allocating only at most 75% of the memory for Spark.
The rest for the operating system and buffer cache.
10 Gigabit or higher network is the best way to make these applications faster.
```

Please share your knowledge if someone used Spark on Prod.

Thanks a ton
    at least 8-16 cores per machine.

May someone please help me on this.

Comment: Do you have a vendor you could ask that could analyze your specific use-case with you? That would probably be the best way to get an acceptable estimate. It depends a lot on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what requirements you have. How is the data structured? How much processing will you do with it? How fast does it need to be? How many jobs will need to be run at the same time? How are your disaster recovery requirements? What about redundancy across clusters? Any restrictions on the hardware vendor?

Comment: @Secespitus: Thanks a ton for valuable information